# Pumping Lemma On Context Free Language

Tags: theory, automata, pumping-lemma

For the language
    {a^2^n | n >= 0}

I understand that first some k is chosen, and then z = uvwxy such that vx != epsilon and #(vwx) <= k, but I can't think of any i which proves that this language is not context free.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for the math or comp sci stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint: if you consider any power of two greater than k (say, 2<sup>k</sup>), then 2<sup>k</sup> + k is not a power of two, since

> 2<sup>k</sup> + k < 2<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup>

See if that can guide you to choose the right string and find your choice of i.

Hope this helps!